# What is optocoupler and how it is used?

Tags: opto-isolator

*Im curious about optocoupler.*

*What is optocoupler,why and how it is used in electronic circuits ?*

Comment: What research have you already done? What do you already know abou this topic, and what specific question about it can we help you with?

Comment: I read about it a little on google,but I do not get it really. I want to know how it is used in circuits and why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select the accompanying components for an optocoupler?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33042/how-do-i-select-the-accompanying-components-for-an-optocoupler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an optocoupler is a device used when you want to electrically isolate a circuit from another circuit that you want to send an electric signal[image]

when you turn on the led it sends photons to the phototransistor, these phototransistor which is like a normal transistor but its "base current" is the light emitted by the led, in this way you can use it as an isolated switch between two circuits

[image: image from https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/294744/mosfet-switch-using-an-optocoupler]
using an optocoupler to control a 12v load with a 3v3 signal

Comment: Is there a reason they usualy put the R1 at pin 2 instead of pin 1?

Comment: i dont see a particular reason, in this circuit instead of the internal LED lighting up with a 3.3V signal it will light up with a 0V signal. a more experienced user could point out a better reason for this but i think is an inheritance from the old bjt transistor low side switching circuits.

Answer (score 0):

> What is an optocoupler?

It's a device that couples an electronic signal from an input to an output optically.  In practice, that means it has an LED for an input, a photodiode or phototransistor for a detector, and possibly some logic or other devices conditioning the output.

> How is it used in electronic circuits?

It's used when you need to communicate between two circuits while maintaining electrical isolation, either as a safety isolation or as a designer convenience.